# Is the C++ `free` function thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, memory-management

That is, if my C++ application allocates memory in one thread using `malloc`, will `free` successfully de-allocate the memory, if called from another thread, or can I expect it to throw an exception?  Both threads belong to the same process.  I am using Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current standard doesn't make any guarantees about threads.  On most implementations, `malloc` and `free` may be called from different threads.  Visual C++ heap code also serializes access to heaps, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If `malloc` and `free` are properly synchronized, deallocating memory in another thread is perfectly fine and safe. Moreover, this claim is correct according to C++0x standard. As @Ashot mentioned, the current C++03 standard deals only with singlethreaded execution model

Comment: I guess it depends on implementation, no?

Comment: @Andrey: Technically, there is no such thing as threads as far as C language is concerned. So it depends more on OS. But I don't know any implementation or OS on which this would be a problem

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan how this is related to OS? Authors can mess with globals without proper thread safety, and it will fail in multithreaded environment

Comment: @Andrey: It is upto the OS to provide the appropriate multi-threading library. Threading is OS functionality thus providing a library to do it (multi-threading) is highly coupled to the OS's.

Comment: @Martin not true. `malloc` is not part of OS, it is part of CRT. You can create your own CRT and sell it. How will OS guarantee thread safety in *your* code?

Comment: @Andrey: But neither will you CRT provide multi-threading so not an issue. Threading libraries OS and CRT are intricately tied together they can not (are not) developed in isolation. But only the OS can provide threading support (its not part of the CRT) it can only be done with consent from the OS if its not supported there is no threading. The thread library depends on the CRT and OS the CRT depends on the OS.

Comment: @Martin "But only the OS can provide threading support (its not part of the CRT) it can only be done with consent from the OS if its not supported there is no threading" - not true. Java had threads that were scheduled by the JVM as a prominent example and worked just fine even on OSes that didn't support threading at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's thread-safe in that sense (the `malloc` pool is process-global, not thread-local), but not in the sense of behaving sanely if called while another thread is calling `malloc()` or `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

The current C++ standard doesn't even know about threads. So in terms of standard I don't think you can tell whether it is ok or not. However all threads in a program share the same address space, so it must be Ok to free object in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

If the C compiler and OS support threads then it will be safe.

If your compiler is on Windows then you want to make sure you are linking with the multi-threaded runtime libraries. Or if your compiler supports a -pthread option or something similar then it's safe also.

If the compiler does have a flag like -pthread then don't assume things are thread-safe unless you use that flag. Using the flag will link in different libraries and set different preprocessor macros. It's entirely possible that a whole different thread-safe C runtime is linked in when that flag is given.